# Accessing codes for functions using methods with asterisk in its name in R

Tags: r, function, methods, random-forest

I am using `randomForest` package in R. I have installed and loaded. Now I want to see the `randomForest()` Function, it says it uses method called `randomForest. I have implemented the following code:

```
   installed.packages("randomForest")
   library(randomForest)
   randomForest
   # function (x, ...) 
   # UseMethod("randomForest")
   # <environment: namespace:randomForest>

   methods(randomForest)
   # [1] randomForest.default* randomForest.formula*
   # see '?methods' for accessing help and source code

   randomForest.default
   # Error: object 'randomForest.default' not found
```

Example for `summary()` function,

```
   summary
   # function (object, ...) 
   # UseMethod("summary")
   # <bytecode: 0x00000000173508c0>
   # <environment: namespace:base>

   methods(summary)
   #  [1] summary,ANY-method             summary,diagonalMatrix-method  summary,mle-method            
   #  [4] summary,sparseMatrix-method    summary.Anova.mlm*             summary.aov                   
   #  [7] summary.aovlist*               summary.aspell*                summary.bag*  

   summary.bag*
   + 

   summary.bag
   # Error: object 'summary.bag' not found
```

As you can see above, few method names have asterisk in it, and rest of them are without them. SO I am able to access codes for methods without asterisk by just typing its name on console.

How to access codes for functions which uses methods having asterisk `*` in its name, what does it signify.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please read the manual pages of the functions you are using (especially when explicitely asked for: _# see '?methods' for accessing help and source code_). `?methods` clearly states: _The S3 method name is followed by an asterisk * if the method definition is not exported from the package namespace in which the method is defined._ There are _no_ asterisks in function names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions that end with an asterisks are not exported in the namespace. They are either S3 methods or functions meant for internal use. You can still call them directly using `getAnywhere(randomForest.default)` or `randomForest:::randomForest.default`